# Java Swing/AWT GUI Locations Wrong

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

So I have an application developed in C# that creates a bunch of controls on command from a button click.  It does a lot of control creation but I've scaled it down to just the first two of a set that it creates, for simplicity.  In the picture below you'll see that I have pressed the Create button (which goes invisible upon clicking) and it made 16 (ability to scroll to see more) text boxes and combo boxes each respectively aligned with each other.

[image: Visual Studio C# Form Application]

Now, I know I should have thought of developing this in a cross platform environment before production, but disregarding that, my main problem now is emulating this application in Java using Swing and AWT GUI objects.

I do have the ability to create the text boxes all in line as shown.
[image: Java Swing/AWT GUI text boxes]

In addition I have the ability to create the combo boxes where I'd want them to be, in line as shown.
[image: Java Swing/AWT GUI combo boxes]

However, once I try to do a dynamic create with both, then the location/positioning gets really messed up.

[image: Java Swing/AWT GUI both]

***Is there an attribute or property that I'm missing?***  The code for the location positioning is below...  They don't have any other attributes turned on or off that are different from their defaults.

```
    panelContainer.add(newComboBox);

    newComboBox.setSize(95, 20);
    newComboBox.setLocation(miniCount * (newComboBox.getWidth() + 10) + 80, 45 + levelCount * 170);
```

---

```
    panelContainer.add(newTextBox);

    newTextBox.setSize(95, 20);
    newTextBox.setLocation(miniCount * (newTextBox.getWidth() + 10) + 80, levelCount * 170);
```

The miniCount and levelCount variables just make sure that we have only 6 (miniCount) items per row and to go to the next row if we need to (levelCount).  The rest of the magic numbers are for positioning of course.

The text boxes are AWT TextFields boxes.  The combo boxes are AWT Choice boxes.

EDIT:
The Java application and C# application are separate.  They ultimately run the same algorithm, but I'm just have trouble making the GUIs act the same.

Comment: Why in the world are you using java stuff in C#?

Comment: Not, this is a totally different application.  Totally in Java, I'm just trying to basically do the same thing that I happened to do in a separate C# application.

Comment: You should strongly consider ditching absolute positioning in favor of a layout manager. That looks an awful lot like a GridLayout to me.

Comment: What I'm using looks like a GridLayout or what I should try to use is GridLayout?  By the way, I am using NetBeans IDE 7.2.1

Comment: @harmonickey You should look into layout managers. Specifically, GridLayout may be the right layout for you. It might not. It has advantages and limitations, but it appears based on one screen shot I spent maybe 5 seconds looking at that it might be applicable. Even if GridLayout is not the right solution for you, using a LayoutManager of some kind is *highly* recommended over absolute positioning.

Comment: If you have not trivial layouts I'd recommend [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) (see the demos).

Comment: Or [Matrix Layout](http://softwaremonkey.org/Code/MatrixLayout).  It is a very rare case indeed where it's beneficial to do GUI layout manually.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) You've described a problem and how you can't do it, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question?

Comment: Each set of text boxes / combo boxes has to be put in its own JPanel.  The layout manager for each JPanel is GridBagLayout.

Comment: It seems my positioning stuff was actually correct but the way I was doing it to adapt to some Java stuff I accidentally ended up with miniCount and levelCount adding 4 each time instead of 1 because it'd add 1 to each variable on each instance creation.  With C# I had separate objects for the box creation, but I decided against that in Java for no particular reason and as a result made miniCount and levelCount global variables.  Bad.